# Best way to save data from flash

Tags: actionscript-3

I have an AS3 document with roughly 200 individual elements I'm trying to save to the database.  I just need to saved information about their physical properties on the stage.

There are many ways to do this, but what is the recommended approach?

The backend is PHP/MySQL and it's not a two-way exchange.  Save it, done.

Comment: tip: read up on object serialization/marshalling with amfphp. amazingly fast, and pretty straightforward to implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

apart from the server side, a good way to store / assign position/rotation/scale is to use the DisplayObjects' transformation matrices:

```
shape.transform.matrix
sprite.transform.matrix
```

it is rather compact ; need to store 6 Numbers per object.
rounding the scale/rotation values down to 5 decimals ( 0.12345 instead of 0.123456789123456 ) and the translation to 1 decimal ( 0.1 instead of 0.123456 ) works pretty well to spare some Ko.
for example this method:

```
private function storeMatrix( displayObject:DisplayObject, decimals:int = 5 ):String 
{
    var str:String = '';
    var m:Matrix = displayObject.transform.matrix;

    str += m.a.toFixed( decimals ) + ':';
    str += m.b.toFixed( decimals ) + ':';
    str += m.c.toFixed( decimals ) + ':';
    str += m.d.toFixed( decimals ) + ':';
    str += m.tx.toFixed( 1 ) + ':';
    str += m.ty.toFixed( 1 );

    return str;
}
```

will return something like:

> -0.95119:-0.30550:0.30550:-0.95119:110.0:110.0

and this method sets the position/rotation/scale from the string:

```
private function assignMatrix( str:String, _do:DisplayObject ):void 
{
    var values:Array = str.split( ':' );
    var m:Matrix = new Matrix();
    m.a = values[ 0 ];
    m.b = values[ 1 ];
    m.c = values[ 2 ];
    m.d = values[ 3 ];
    m.tx = values[ 4 ];
    m.ty = values[ 5 ];
    _do.transform.matrix = m;
}
```

once you've collected all the object's matrices, you can serialize them with AMF and store to database. last time I did that, I used [FZIP](http://codeazur.com.br/lab/fzip/) to compress the data even further ( 500Ko->20Ko). I don't think it'll help in your case, just wanted to point it out :)

NB: if needed, you can also store the transform.ColorTransform properties of an object in the very same way.

Comment: I'm selecting this as the answer because it brought me closest to my actual solution.  Using the transform matrix.  I haven't implemented AMF yet in favor is a simple post to an external script.

Answer (score 2):

I would check out flash remoting/AMFPHP:  http://amfphp.sourceforge.net/

It's pretty straightforwad, and really easy to implement.

Hope this helps.